# Can't get nginx to flush buffer with php7-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I have a need for a longish-running (7-8 seconds) php script to output partial results to the user as they are found. I have previously been able to accomplish this with an older version of php-fpm and nginx by doing the following:

1. Using these config settings in php:

```
@ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ob_end_clean();
set_time_limit(0);
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
```

and running `ob_implicit_flush(1); flush();` every time I needed to output partial results.

2. Using these directives for nginx:

```
 fastcgi_keep_conn on;
 proxy_buffering off;
 gzip off;
```

However, with an upgrade to PHP 7 and nginx 1.10.3, these settings no longer work.

I have tried adding these directives to nginx:

```
 fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
 fastcgi_store off;
 fastcgi_buffering off;
```

But these don't seem to do anything, either. The results are still buffered until php script finishes running and then sent all at once.

Is what I am asking for still possible?

(I appreciate suggestions that there are other ways to send partial results that don't involve disabling buffers, but that's not part of my question).

Answer (score 1):

Think the only way you can do that is if you can split the initial script in multiple scripts.

Each script you can then call from frontend using ajax and append the content to the dom.

PHP scripts are sync for the most part. But by doing ajax calls (those run async) you can execute multiple php scripts in parallel.

Comment: Why did this work in prior versions of php-fpm + nginx? What has changed?